# How do I loop through results and store them in a list so I can use them in my Django template

Tags: python, django

I tried to loop thorough an object and store and store the results in a list so i could use it in my django template and display it. I tried to copy something I have elsewhere in my code to suit my needs but it doesnt work. I tried to duplicate this

```
{% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
      {{ tag.post_set.all }}
{% endfor %}
```

this returns everything in one block. I want to be able to loop through it so I tried this

```
links = []
for t in tag:
   links.append(
       t.post_set.all()
   )

mylink = links
context = {
    "title": "detail ",
    "instance": instance,
    "hops": mylink
}
```

but it didn't work. What's the proper syntax to tore my results from a loop and store them in a list I can then use in my template. All help or advice is welcome

EDIT:

my view

```
 def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    tag = instance.tags.all
    links = []
    for t in tag:
       links.append(
           t.post_set.distinct()
       )

   share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
   tag = instance.tags.all()
   context = {
       "title": "detail ",
       "instance": instance,
       "share_string": share_string,
       "tag": tag
   }
   return render(request, "posts/post_detail.html", context)



 class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:tag_index", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

   class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True,
                              width_field="width_field",
                              height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]


def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
       return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

this is what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to do a single query for the posts you want.

```
links = Post.objects.filter(link__tag__instancemodel=instance)
```

where `instancemodel` is the name of whatever model `instance` is.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't have an *inner loop* in the template:

```
{% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
      {% for post in tag.post_set.all %}
          {{ post }}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @alexcxe Thanks for the response. The way that I wanted to do it I think I'd be able to return distinct(). Distinct doesn't work in the template

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in another answer. [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136211/1677912) has the correct template syntax.

You should be trying to minimize the business logic happening in templates since render performance is already bad enough. Move the distinct logic into your Python code.
Using [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) might work out for you

```
links = []
for t in tag:
   links.append(
       t.post_set.distinct()
   )
```

Keeps the template logic basic

Just access and store the tags directly from the model and return them in the context. instance.tags **should** return a query-set if I'm not mistaken, meaning you can simply call distinct() on tags.

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    tags = instance.tags.distinct()

    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)

    context = {
        "title": "detail ",
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "tags": tags
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_detail.html", context)
```

Your template should be something like:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
      {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'method' object is not iterable. This was the question I was posing. How to stor results of a loop into a list so I can use it. I don't know how to.

Comment: Alright, it may make it easier to answer if you provided the model structure.

Comment: Edited my answer to something that may help out?

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out but that way doesn't work either. I have been experimenting with adding tags and removing them. For every tag that I ad it lists all the posts connected to it. causing it to repeat. So for every tag a new list is generated. I even tried the set method. Which didn't work either, which is why I wanted to pack for loop results into a list and iterate it in my template.